# Yii : Multiple activeCheckboxlist with same model

Tags: yii

has just started out Yii web app and encountered this problem, any suggestions are welcome:)

What i am trying to achieve:
-To display a form with tabs, each tab content contains a list of checkboxes from the same model.
-so user can select some items from tab 1, some from tab 2, etc and then click submit button to process.

Problem:
But i couldn't think of anyway such that the last tab activecheckboxlist will not clobbered the previous one up.
I am trying to to something similar to this : [www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/20388-2-checkboxlist-and-1-model]

but instead of fixing it at 2, mine is dynamic.

What i have done so far:

```
<?php
    $tabArray = array();
    foreach ((Product::model()->listParentChild(0)) as $productparent) {
        array_push($tabArray, array(
            'label' => $productparent['name'],
            'content' => CHtml::activeCheckBoxList(
                    $model, 'products', CHtml::listData(Product::model()->listParentChild($productparent['id']), 'id', 'name'), array(
                'labelOptions' => array('style' => 'display:inline'),
                'template' => '<div class="check-option">{input} {label}</div>',
                'separator' => '',
                    )
            ), 'active' => ($productparent['id'] == 1 ? true : false),
        ));
    }
    ?>   

    <?php
    $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbTabs', array(
        'type' => 'tabs', // 'tabs' or 'pills'
        'placement' => 'left',
        'tabs' => $tabArray,
    ));
    ?>
```

and in my product model:

```
 public function listParentChild($parentid) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM piki_product WHERE parentid=:parentid";        
    $productlist = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql);
    $productlist->bindValue(":parentid", $parentid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    return $productlist->queryAll();
}
```

any suggestions will be appreciated.. :/

Comment: This is less a Yii thing and more a software architecture thing in general -- the common problem of dynamic nesting. So, first, what about your DB structure. Why -- if this is what you want to do -- have you not created a separate relational DB table for the child-parent relationships. Next, your going to have to write a method in your controller to first sort and set the depth of the parent-child hierarchies present in your data. THEN you can create the UI. This is what you are after, right?

Comment: I didn't have the extra child-parent relationship table. I will add in that later to try things out.

but then again, how would that enable me to update a single model with multiple activecheckboxlist?

Comment: Yeah, I don't know that you have to, but that is a common practice when building dynamically nested lists. The key is the method on your controller which will sort the records and categorize them. That's the hard part. Part of the reason for a relational table -- no need to mess with the full data table when doing those calculations.

Comment: hmm. Thanks Thanks. Will think thru the child-parent relationship table first since it would probably be useful later on too :)

Comment: Sure. Headed to work in few, but tweet at me @barnes_cliff if you get stuck ... always happy to help a fellow Yii-er :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could be wrong, but I don't think cliffbarnes is on the right track with his comments about dynamic nesting.  As far as I can tell, you're only dealing with one level of child products; it's just that there could be multiple sets of these child products.

In that case, the link you sited actually offers the correct solution:

```
<?php echo CHtml::checkBoxList('array1', CHtml::listData(Atributos::model()-> findAllByAttributes(array('tipo'=>'talla')), 'id_atributo','valor'))?>

<?php echo CHtml::checkBoxList('array2', CHtml::listData(Atributos::model()-> findAllByAttributes(array('tipo'=>'talla')), 'id_atributo','valor'))?>
```

Each set of checkboxes is given a different name (array1, and array2), so that each field's selected values doesn't override the other.  In your case, the solution is the same; you just need to make the field names dynamic. I.E.

```
foreach ((Product::model()->listParentChild(0)) as $productparent) {
  $fieldname = 'product' . $productparent['id'];
  echo CHtml::checkBoxList($fieldname, ... (etc)
```

Within your controller you would check to see whether there are results for each dynamic field name.

```
foreach ((Product::model()->listParentChild(0)) as $productparent) {
  if (isset($_POST['product' . $productparent['id']]) {
    // Add values to $model->product
  }
}
```

An even better solution would be to output each checkbox individually, so you can create one array of results, indexed by child ID.

```
foreach ((Product::model()->listParentChild(0)) as $productparent) {
  foreach (Product::model()->listParentChild($productparent['id']) as $child) {
    CHtml::checkBox("product[{$child['id']}]", ... (etc)
```

Then in your controller, all you'd have to do is this:

```
if (isset($_POST['product']) && count($_POST['product']) > 0) {
  $model->product = array_keys($_POST['product']);
}
```

This solution does not work with activeCheckBoxList().  It would work if you wanted to override the `__get()` and `__set()` magic methods to make these dynamic property names available to your model, but that's probably over kill.

**Edit (as per request)**

If you need to have default selections for your checkboxes, you can just pass them as the second argument of `CHtml::checkBoxList()`.  http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#checkBoxList-detail

But if you still want to use `__get()` and `__set()`, here's an example:

```
class YourModel extends CActiveRecord {
    // I usually create a placeholder to contain the values of my virtual attribute
    protected $_childValues = array();

    public function __get($name) {
        // The following regular expression finds attributes
        // with the name product_{parent ID}
        if (preg_match("/^product_\d+$/", $name)) {
            // I put the underscore in the name so I could get
            // parent ID easier.
            list($junk, $id) = explode("_", $name);
            if (!isset($this->_childValues[$id])) {
                $this->_childValues[$id] = array();
            }
            return $this->_childValues[$id];
        }
        else {
            // Make sure to still call the parent's __get() method
            return parent::__get($name);
        }
    }

    public function __set($name, $value) {
        // Same regex as above
        if (preg_match("/^product_\d+$/", $name)) {
            list($junk, $id) = explode("_", $name);
            $this->_childValues[$id] = $value;
        }
        else {
            // Make sure to still call the parent's __set() method
            parent::__set($name, $value);
        }
    }
}

$model = new YourModel;

// Any property in the format of product_{parent ID} is available
// through your model.
echo $model->product_1;
$model->product_300 = array();
```

You might also consider checking to see if the parent ID in a property name corresponds with a parent ID in the database, instead of just allowing any property in that format to pass through.

Comment: Hi ethan, thanks for your suggestions. Could you also roughly share how would i override the 'magic' methods?

The reason is that i might not be able to use the 2 methods you mentioned because some of the checkboxes are pre-checked. But i will give it that a try first since i couldn't think of any other ways already.

Comment: I used the CHtml::checkBoxList() as per your suggestion and got things working. Thanks lots! Guess i have some optimisation work to do next as i have a total of 3 nested for loops for this function and its kind of slowing things down even on localhost. see ya around!